# saving space delimited files and reading it back

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I saved this file as a “Formatted Text (Space delimited)”. When I open it using excel the content in cell F7 is moved over to D7. Please see the attachment.  Would I have to add “space saving” text to a7, b7, d7, & e7 or is there another way of doing this ?

Saved space delimited file:
[image: Saved space delimited file]

enter image description here:
[image]

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Main Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+P
'

'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+P
'
       Range("C7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ENTER_FAILURE"
    Range("F7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("G7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("H7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("I7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("G7:I7").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G7:O7"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("G7:O7").Select


    Dim n As Integer
    Dim colmm As Integer
    Dim origFILEname As String: origFILEname = ActiveSheet.Name
    Dim newName As String: newName = origFILEname & " + " & CStr(0)
    Dim tstCaseCount As Double: tstCaseCount = 0

        For colmm = 4 To 12 Step 1
    ' Copy orginal sheet and make copy active sheet
            Call CopySheetAndRename(origFILEname, newName)

    'innter loop will deal with inputting failures
        For n = 36 To 56 Step 1
          ActiveSheet.Cells(n, colmm) = 8888
        Next n

    'add code that save txt file here
    SaveToRelativePath

    'Increment test case count
    tstCaseCount = tstCaseCount + 1
    newName = origFILEnMAE & " + " & CStr(tstCaseCount)
        Next colmm



End Sub


Sub CopySheetAndRename(xOrignalFileName As String, NwName As String)
    'create a new sheet and rename it
        Sheets(xOrignalFileName).Copy after:=Sheets(1)
        On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = NwName
End Sub


Sub SaveToRelativePath()
    Dim relativePATH As String

    'make failure red sub
    MkFailureRed

    'save ffile name as space delimited (*.prn) in the current folder
relativePATH = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".prn"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePATH, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter, CreateBackup:=False

    'save file name as workbook
relativePATH = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePATH, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub

Sub MkFailureRed()

    'add after to make index number red
        With Selection.Font
                .Color = -16776961
                .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    'make all the failure red
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=-3
        Range("D12").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=-93
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:="=-50"
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you use VBA for any of this?

Comment: yes, it is written in vb. I take an text file and edit it using VB macro.

Comment: In that case it might be useful to include that code in your question.

Comment: Please take a look at the sample code when you get a chance...

Comment: There's nothing there at your link.  *Post your code in your question*.

Comment: My apologies. The code is posted now...

Comment: And then exactly how are you re-opening the file?  And why not save it as tab-delimited, which is a bit more "typical" and easier to deal with ?  Is there a specific need for a space-delimited file type?

Comment: I agree with you that a tab-delimited is more typical but i am working with a preexisting solution. As a result, I am stuck with the space delimited file type.
The purpose of the automation tool is to edit a preexisting space delimited file and save it in two formats (space delimited and an excel file type).    When I open the file backup I used excel. I could use anything to open the file but I always use excel.

Comment: *Exactly how* do you open the prn file in excel?

Comment: I go to file open and find the space delimited file. When the dialog appear you have to make sure “all files” is Selected. 

Once you select the file you want,you  have to select Delimited, Next, Comma, Space, and then Finish. You could also just press D, N, C, S,F.

Comment: What about the "treat consecutive delimiters as one" setting?  That would collapse multiple spaces into a single space if checked, and explain what you're seeing.  Try opening the file in Word and turning on the "show formatting" to visualize the spaces: how does it compare to your original file?

Comment: OK I never use prn format, but after a quick look, it's really a fixed-width format (where each field is assigned a fixed number of characters).  Excel make a best-guess at what those column widths should be when exporting to prn, but something as simple as changeing the column widths in excel can impact that, so you have to be careful when using this format.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/100433/export-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-fixed-width-text-file